# Riemannian geometry of Grassmannian bundles

Tags: reference-request, riemannian-geometry, fibre-bundles, grassmannians

The Grassmannian bundle of a vector bundle $E$ is a smooth manifold where each fiber over the base space is replaced by the Grassmannian (of specified rank) of the fiber. I am interested in defining a natural metric and local co-ordinates on this space to compute Riemannian quantities like the gradient and Hessian on it. Is there a good reference for such computations? Ideally, I am looking for something like [this](https://www.cis.upenn.edu/%7Ecis610/Diffgeom-Grassmann.Absil.pdf) but any step towards it would be appreciated.

If it helps, my base space is another Grassmannian.

Comment: For the metric on each fiber, it's natural to take the unique (up to scaling) metric invariant under the unitary / orthogonal group. But an overall metric requires more data than the metric on the fiber and the metric on the base, and I believe there is no canonical choice of this except in special cases.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! So in my application it turns out that a certain flag manifold can be fibered with a Grassmannian both as a base space and the fiber on it (though of different dimensions). This makes a canonical choice of metric and other computations quite simple.